# Probability of choosing same number

Tags: probability

There are four friends – Adam, Bella, Christopher and Drew. All of them are asked to choose any number in their mind. Now what is the probability that every one of them has the same number in mind? The chosen number must be in between 1 to 5 (including 1 and 5).

Comment: i have seen answer to this question as 101/125 in another website, but i think that is wrong

Comment: $\frac{1}{125}$. The first person has some number, and then the chance is $\frac{1}{5}$ that a given other person also has this number.

Comment: There is the issue of whether or not the number chosen is done so *uniformly at random* or not.  It is in fact much more common for people to choose the number 3 or 4 when asked to pick a number from 1 to 5.  This leaves the realm of mathematics and enters the realm of psychology.  If each person picks uniformly at random, the answer will indeed be $\frac{1}{125}$

Comment: thats correct, thanks JMoravitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality, let's say Adam picks first. The probability that the other 3 choose the exact same number as Adam is $\frac{1}{5}*\frac{1}{5}*\frac{1}{5}$, which gives the result of $\frac{1}{125}$.

Note: this answer presumes that the numbers are chosen at random.

Answer (score 1):

**Another way to see the problem.**
Total number of outcomes when 4 people are free to choose a number between 1 and 5 are equal to $5^4$ (or $625$)
Outcomes when everyone chooses the same number are $5$.
Hence, probability = $\frac{5}{625}$ = $\frac{1}{125}$